# How To use a factory method along with an interface

Tags: c#, interface, factory-method

I'am using .Net 4.7.2 and C# 7

I want to provide data by using *XamlServices.Load* 
Usually, I would use something like this

```
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Xaml;

[assembly: XmlnsDefinition( "http://MyNamespace.de" , "MyNamespace" )]

namespace MyNamespace
{

    public class MyExecutingClass
    {
        private void Load()
        {            
            var targetClass = XamlServices.Load( @"C:\MyFile.xml" ) as TargetClass;
            // ...
        }
    }


    public class TargetClass
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }

    }
}
```

The content of the file looks like this:

```
<TargetClass xmlns="http://MyNamespace.de" Value="5" />
```

In my case I don't have access to *TargetClass*, but to it's interface *ITargetClass*

So the code looks like this:

```
public class MyExecutingClass
{
    private void Load()
    {            
        var targetClass = XamlServices.Load( @"C:\MyFile.xml" ) as ITargetClass;
        // ...
    }

}

public interface ITargetClass
{
    int Value { get; set; }

}

/// <summary>
/// I can't access this class from the Load method
/// </summary>
internal class TargetClass : ITargetClass
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

}
```

And the content:

```
<ITargetClass xmlns="http://MyNamespace.de" Value="5" />
```

XamlServices.Load tries to instanciate ITargetClass, which fails, because you can't instanciate an interface.

A MissingMethodException is thrown which says:
*Default constructor not found for type ITargetClass The type can be created with the arguments or the factory method directive.*

What implementation do I need?

**Addition**

What I basically need is a line like this:

```
ITargetClass targetClass = new ITargetClass();
```

I know, that this is not possible the way I wrote it. But could a factory method help me? How would it has to look like?

Comment: Are you able to access the class in the Xaml? If you can, then the code can stay as shown in the updated snippet and the Xaml uses the concrete class.

Comment: No, I can access the interface only. There is no chance that can use the concrete class

Comment: Ok confusing, then how do you know that there even is a concrete implementation of the interface? You may need to provide more details to clarify the actual problem.

Comment: Because I can look at the class, but I can't access it from code. It's this way by design and I am in no position to change that, I have to work with it, like it is.